# FB Graph API likes/user_likes not returning anything

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to read the user's feed and parse it. I am having trouble with trying to see if a user has liked a post or not.

In FQL I can do this:

```
SELECT likes FROM stream WHERE post_id = '59685491632_10152603637976633'
```

That works fine, but to my knowledge FQL is going to be deleted soon and I will be stuck again.

In the Graph API I tried this:

postId/likes/user_likes, but that didn't return anything other than all of the likes.

This is what FQL returns, and what I am trying to get in the Graph API. I need the user_likes variable and there is no documentation on how to do that with the new API.

> ```
>   "likes":  {
>     "href":  "https://www.facebook.com/browse/likes/?id=10152603637976633", 
>     "count":  2941, 
>     "sample":  [
>        "752940741418358", 
>        "816307018398608", 
>        "10152367777559604", 
>        "736860723056935"
>     ], 
>     "friends":  [
>     ], 
>     "user_likes":  false, 
>     "can_like":  true
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using non-existing endpoints. There is no `/{post_id}/likes/user_likes`, and you cannot get this info from the Graph API as from FQL. Except you read all the likes, and make a lookup if the current `user_id` is among them.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/likes
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post#fields

Graph API v2.0 and therefore FQL will be usable until August 7th 2016, see

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog (first table)
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions#howlong

Comment: maybe, but since you most likely will not get read_stream approved, it does not really matter ;)

Comment: @luschn is correct. You probably won't get the according permission approved